# Dual monitors not working after 18.04.4 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, toshiba-satellite

I updated my Toshiba Satellite L500 laptop to Ubuntu 18.04.4, and started having problems with dual displays.

For example I get into my user account, I connect my secondary display, and both displays start flashing black and grey repeatedly. When I disconnect the other display it gets back to the desktop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.